# Having issue with SKEffectNode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit, skeffectnode

I am following Apple's SpriteKit documentation, now I am trying to use SKEffectNode, but my problem is the effect will not be applied!  Here is my code :

```
SKEffectNode *lightingNode = [[SKEffectNode alloc] init];
SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spaceship"]];
SKSpriteNode *light = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
self.filter = [self blurFilter];
lightingNode.position = self.view.center;
lightingNode.blendMode = SKBlendModeAdd;
[lightingNode addChild: light];
[self addChild:lightingNode];

//applying blur 

- (CIFilter *)blurFilter
{
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBoxBlur"]; // 3
    [filter setDefaults];
    [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:20] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
    return filter;
}
```

When you run the app it just show spaceship without any blur effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like @"CIBoxBlur" filter doesn't exist anymore, at least in iOS 7.0. You can use @"CIGaussianBlur". You can see full list of the filters by running:

```
    NSArray* filters = [CIFilter filterNamesInCategories:nil];
    for (NSString* filterName in filters)
    {
        NSLog(@"Filter: %@", filterName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere that you're setting the [`filter`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEffectNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEffectNode/filter) property of the effect node you've created, nor where you're setting its [`shouldEnableEffects`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEffectNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEffectNode/shouldEnableEffects) property to `YES`.

As implied by the aforelinked documentation, both of those properties need a meaningful value if your effect node is to apply a filter.

Comment: Thanks , I modified    `lightingNode.filter = [self blurFilter];` and add  `shouldEnableEffects` but still nothing happens !

Comment: Hm. I also don't see anything positioning `light` within `lightingNode`'s coordinate space. That might be it.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code with the following changes and all tested great!

```
//switch this  
lightingNode.position
//to this
light.position 
//add this 
lightingNode.shouldEnableEffects = YES;
//change 
CIBoxBlur
//to
CIGaussianBlur
```